# Can email hosting be separated from website hosting?

Tags: email, dns, hosting, tld, webfaction

I've just built a website for a customer which I'm currently hosting on [Webfaction](http://webfaction.com/). I now want to point their company-TLD to the website I built, but I don't want to create an email nightmare for that company.

So my question; is it possible to only host the website of a domain on webfaction and leave the email hosting as it is now? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is yes you can leave email hosting as if for now.

You can also migrate email services from webfaction from which you are taking hosting or you can get email services later from many hosting companies.

For my website I took email services from [host preneur](http://www.hostpreneur.net/web-services/migration-services/) because when I bought my domain I did not think that email service was required then.